# Vue.js change placeholder of text input according to v-model value

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, jquery-select2

I need to change placeholder of a text input via Vue.js data binding. Here is my code.

```html
<select2 :options="power_options" v-model="power">
    <option selected value="hp">hp</option>
    <option value="kW">kW</option>
</select2>

<input name="power_to" type="text" 
    class="form-control pwer_change" v-model="power_from"
    placeholder='[[ power ]]' style="display: inline;width: 48%;">

<input name="power_from" type="text" 
    class="form-control pwer_change" v-model="power_to"
    placeholder="[[ power ]]" style="display: inline;width: 48%;">
```

Here is my vue code...

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#el',
  delimiters: ["[[", "]]"],
  data: {
    power: "hp",
    power_from: null,
    power_to: null,
  },
  created() {

  },
  methods: {

  }
});
```

I have changed `{{` delimiters to `[[` and using `select2` Wrapper Component. I need to change `power_to` and `power_from` input **placeholders** according to `v-model="power"`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should use placeholder property notation in this case `:placeholder="[[ power ]]"`:

```
<input
  name="power_to"
  type="text"
  class="form-control pwer_change"
  v-model="power_from"
  :placeholder="[[ power ]]"
  style="display: inline;width: 48%;"
/>
```

Comment: you are welcome. In case if you need to add some static words to placeholder, the syntax needs to be this: `:placeholder="'Enter value of ' + [[ power ]]"`.