# How to use a variable value as placeholder in Vue with typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

`<input type="text" placeholder="{{fromTimeWindow}}" v-model="fromTimeWindow"/>`

or`<input type="text" v-bind:placeholder="{{fromTimeWindow}}" v-model="fromTimeWindow"/>`

both of the above above code gives me error. I want to use variable "fromTimeWindow" value as placeholder.

Comment: Just use `v-bind:placeholder="fromTimeWindow"`. You can't use moustache in attribute value binding anyway.

Answer (score 9):

You dont have to `{{ }}` since you are binding it to your placeholder. To solve that change your code to this.

```
<input type="text" :placeholder="fromTimeWindow" v-model="fromTimeWindow"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: () => {
  return {
    fromTimeWindow: 'Hey here is custom placeholder'
    }
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<input type="text" :placeholder="fromTimeWindow" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ahhh.. Got the answer from : [Vue.js change placeholder of text input according to v-model value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53706390/vue-js-change-placeholder-of-text-input-according-to-v-model-value)
.

We need to use it like this:

```
<input type="text" :placeholder="[[fromTimeWindow]]" v-model="fromTimeWindow"/>
```

Comment: You dont even need `[[]]` scope

Comment: yeah. removed it after your comment. Thanks :)